# How can I set "global" variables that can be accessed in controllers and models in Rails

Tags: ruby, variables, ruby-on-rails-4, global-variables, activesupport-concern

I have a table that has set entries. I would like to access those entries as variables in both my models and controllers without querying the database every time to set those variables.

I am able to get it to work by creating duplicate "concerns" for my models and controllers. I could also set global variables in my ApplicationController. Or i could initialize them in every place that I need them. What would be the correct rails way to set and access global variables that can be accessed in both controllers and models?

```rb
class ItemType
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  belongs_to :item_type
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Foo 
  has_many :items  

  def build_item
    bar_item_type = ItemType.find_by(:name => "bar")

    self.items.build(
      :foo_id => self.id,
      :item_type_id => bar_item_type.id
    )
  end
end

class ItemsController
  def update
    bar_item_type = ItemType.find_by(:name => "bar")

    @item.update(:item_type_id => bar_item_type.id)
  end

end
```

In the example, you can see that I am declaring the `bar_item_type` variable in both my Foo model and my ItemsController. I would like to DRY up my code base by being able to create and access that variable once for my rails project instead of having to make that same database call everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure your example makes it clear WHY you want to do this.  Will you really use `ItemType.find_by(:name => "bar")` in your application? Use of global variables for your use case breaks MVC and basic Rails conventions.  You first need to ask yourself WHY you think you need to do this.  There are likely better more conventional ways to do it.

Comment: I guess that is my question. What is the conventional/better way to do this using the example above? I would like a variable that is accessible in both of these use cases.

Comment: The problem is, how can you be sure `ItemType.find_by(:name => "bar")` will even return anything?  Your code makes assumptions about the database.

Comment: The database is seeded with specific item_types. The database is assumed and designed to have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you MUST use a constant, there are a few ways to do it. But you must take into account that you are instantiating an ActiveRecord model object which is dependent on data being present in the database.  This is not recommend, because you now have model and controller logic relying on data being present in the database. This might be ok if you have seeded your database and that it won't change.

```
class ItemType
  BAR_TYPE ||= where(:name => "bar").limit(1).first 

  has_many :items
end
```

Now where ever you need this object you can call it like this:

```
bar_item_type  = ItemType::BAR_TYPE
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe this is what I'm looking for. I was unaware you could declare `BAR_TYPE` on the ItemType model like this.

Comment: This is valid ruby syntax but not exactly conventional Rails style.  Surya's answer below is much more conventional Rails way and has some added benefits, where as my example is more of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I would advocate against such hard-coded or DB state-dependent code. If you must do it, here's how one of the ways I know it can be done:

```
# models
class ItemType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  # caches the value after first call
  def self.with_bar
    @@with_bar ||= transaction { find_or_create_by(name: "bar") }
  end

  def self.with_bar_id
    with_bar.id
  end
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item_type
  belongs_to :foo

  scope :with_bar_types, -> { where(item_type_id: ItemType.with_bar_id) }
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items  

  # automatically sets the foo_id, no need to mention explicitly
  # the chained with_bar_types automatically sets the item_type_id to ItemType.with_bar_id
  def build_item
    self.items.with_bar_types.new
  end
end

# Controller
class ItemsController
  def update
    @item.update(item_type_id: ItemType.with_bar_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: OP may want to also validate uniqueness of name on the item type

Comment: @lacostenycoder: Then OP should mention that in the example code in the post. Anyway, it's pretty easy to get around it.

Comment: I agree, and also think you have provided a  fine answer.